# How to implement a raycasting inside Spritekit

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, raycasting

I want to check if a laser beam (a line) goes through objects and at which points. Currently I'm recreating the Asteroids project by grapefrukt. For more details you check this video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MeJ76z2Ncyg&t=622s).

There is a method called `hitTestWithSegmentFromPoint`.. inside SceneKit  but I want to achieve the effect only using Spritekit.

[image]
Edit 1: I need to know the position of the black circles (the points of intersection). The asteroid is with red color, the beam is green.

Edit 2: I was hopeful that the @Knight0fDragon solution will work.. but it didn't. Since the line appears through the box it doesn't detect the first contact correctly.. nor the second (when leaving the box)

The white circle is the contact point.. the purple arrows point to where the contact points should be. The blue circle is the ship :)

I also made when the collision is detected to make the boxes physics bodies not dynamic (stoping them from moving)

[image]

Edit 3: Closer image to see where physics bodies are using `showsPhysics`

[image]

Edit 4: How I make the white circle

```
let firstBody = contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask > contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask ? contact.bodyB : contact.bodyA
 let secondBody = contact.bodyA == firstBody ? contact.bodyB : contact.bodyA

if firstBody.categoryBitMask == UInt32(1){

    secondBody.isDynamic = false;

    // run only once 
    print(contact.contactPoint);
    createCircleDebug(x: contact.contactPoint.x, y: contact.contactPoint.y, radius: 5)

}


func createCircleDebug (x:CGFloat, y:CGFloat, radius:CGFloat){

    let shape = SKShapeNode.init(circleOfRadius: radius);
    shape.strokeColor = SKColor.white;
    shape.position = CGPoint(x: x, y: y);

    self.addChild(shape);

}
```

Edit 5: Relative line path. The circle is still off.

[image]

Edit 6: Line is now a rectangle using the new code for creating it

[image]

Edit 7: Using Spritenode instead of circle

[image]

Comment: Are you using SKPhysics?

Comment: Yes I do. I will provide a screenshot with the information I need. Because I don't just need to know if the beam collide with bodies

Answer (score 1):

The Apple documentation includes a guide on ray casting with SKPhysics:

[Searching the World for Physics Bodies](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skphysicsworld/searching_the_world_for_physics_bodies)

To find the nearest physics body that the ray hits, you can use [`body(alongRayStart:end:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skphysicsworld/1449613-body). This is a method on `SKPhysicsWorld`.

There is also [`enumerateBodies(alongRayStart:end:using:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skphysicsworld/1449615-enumeratebodies) if you want to get *all* bodies that are hit by the ray and where they were hit. This method calls your block for each physics body that the ray touches, with the following arguments:

- `body`: The physics body that the ray intersected.
- `point`: The point in scene coordinates where the ray contacted the physics body.
- `normal`: The normal vector for the physics body at the point of contact.
- `stop`: A pointer to a Boolean variable. Your block can set this to true to terminate the enumeration.

Comment: `EnumerateBodies` gives you the intersection point and direction for each of the bodies

Answer (score 0):

Normally I would do what ford said (It was the answer I was going to provide after you answered my question),  but if you need to know points of intersection I would create an `SKNode` with an `SKPhysicsBody(polygonFrom:)` and use contactBegins to get the intersection point

```
func rayCast(start:CGPoint,end:CGPoint){

        let mid = CGPoint((end.x + start.x) / 2,(end.y + start.y) / 2)
        let relativeStart1 = CGPoint(start.x - mid.x - 1,start.y - mid.y)
        let relativeEnd1 = CGPoint(end.x - mid.x - 1,end.y - mid.y-1)
        let relativeStart2 = CGPoint(start.x - mid.x + 1,start.y - mid.y)
        let relativeEnd2 = CGPoint(end.x - mid.x + 1,end.y - mid.y)

        let node = SKNode()
        let linePath = UIBezierPath()
        linePath.move(to: relativeStart1)
        linePath.addLine(to: relativeEnd1)
        linePath.addLine(to: relativeEnd2)
        linePath.addLine(to: relativeStart2)
        linePath.closeSubPath()    
        if let physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(polygonFrom:linePath.cgPath){
            physicsBody.categoryBitMask = 0x80000000  //whatever you want it to be
            physicsBody.contactBitMask = ~physicsBody.categoryBitMask //touch everything but the line
            physicsBody.collisionBitMask = 0
            physicsBody.affectedByGravity = false
            node.physicsBody = physicsBody
        }
        scene.addChild(node)
        node.position = mid
}



func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

    let firstBody = contact.bodyA.categeroyBitMask > contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask ? contact.bodyA : contact.bodyB
    let secondBody = contact.bodyA = firstBody ? contact.bodyB : contact.bodyA

    if firstBody.categoryBitMask == 0x80000000{
       //use contact at this point to check intersection points
       //https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skphysicscontact
    }

}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194916/discussion-on-answer-by-knight0fdragon-how-to-implement-a-raycasting-inside-spri).